# How to host a common back-end code of Firebase for React and React-native without compromising the real-time feature?

Tags: express, reactjs, firebase, real-time, react-native

We (me and my team) are building a food delivery real-time Web and Mobile app (using react-native) which also includes payment integration and admin dashboard for a client.

The tech stack we've chosen for the app:

**View**

- React (Web app)
- React-native (Mobile app)

**Back-end**

- Express
- Firebase

We thought of sharing the app data using a **common back-end** for the web and mobile app. Basically, we would've created an **API** that provides the **end-points using Express** and then **Express would Save/Retrieve data to/from Firebase**. Express would be our **middle-ware**.

We created 2 project folders keeping first of all only web app in mind:

- react-webapp
- express-webapp

And then, we start the respective server for the packages.

**Unfortunately**, API's aren't real-time and we may have to implement our mechanism to make the flow real-time.

So, we switched to **merging firebase with react**. We decided that'll use express just for sending emails. So, the folder structure for the web app is something like:

- react-webapp

  - node_modules
  - public
  - src
  - firebase

With this approach, we created a demo and we do get **real-time updates** and we can also use **ReactFireMixin**. Later we can use the same folder and add it to react-native as well for Saving/Retrieving data from the database.

My question is, as we don't have any prior experience of building a Web and Mobile app with a common database/back-end and React/React-native, is this approach apt? Is there anyway in which we can segregate the front-end code from the back-end and utilize the real-time feature of firebase?

The reason for segregating the backend from front-end is to keep a common real-time backend for react and react-native without having to keep 2 separate firebase folders for the web and mobile app.

**Note:** If you are wondering why real-time then the client has asked for a real-time order placement mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

It may work to use socket.io with express to allow for realtime back end updates that come from firebase.